# Bridge Ethernet and wifi on Raspberry Pi 3 to reach ethernet device

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ethernet

I have a raspberry Pi 3 that is connected to a measurement device through the Ethernet port and that provides a WiFi network using dnsmasq. As things are now, I can send command to the device from my laptop by sending them first to a "server" application on the raspberry that sends them to the device via ethernet.
What I'd like to do now is to be able to contact the device directly from my laptop, since the device has it's own server application that provides a web app that allows you to configure the instrument itself.
Knowing that the Raspberri Wifi and the raspberry ethernet have two different IP addresses classes, is there a way to "bridge" the wlan and the eth interfaces in order to communicate directly with the device, and to keep the ability to pass through the raspberry "server" application I mentioned in the previous lines?

I apologize for my lack of clarity, but I hope that someone among you will be able to get what I mean and help me somehow.

Every kind of suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I’m trying to connect my Pi to a device through direct ethernet connexion. Could you tell me how you set this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bridge an Ethernet network interface with an Access Point WLAN interface. There are many tutorials about this, even the Foundation has it here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md ... make sure to scroll down to the lower part where the bridge configuration is given.